# Can Spring Boot load case-sensitive Map keys from environment variables?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Setting an environment variable

```
MYAPP_MYMAP_CaseSensitive=foo
```

for a Map property of Spring Boot's (2.1.7.RELEASE) `@ConfigurationProperties`

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
class MyProperties {
    private Map<String, String> myMap;
    // getters, setters...
}
```

loads the Map with keys in lowercase:

```
{casesensitive=foo}
```

So far I found a workaround using `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON`:

```
SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON={"myapp.myMap":{"CaseSensitive":"foo"}}
```

Is there a correct way to set case-sensitive keys via environment variables?

Comment: I am unsure you can do that directly, check https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/bind/Binder.java which uses https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/source/ConfigurationPropertyName.java and here is a better description https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/relaxed-binding-2.0 so it looks like they force this lowercase conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can't at the moment. This is something we'd like to improve in the future. That improvement is being tracked by [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18003).

In the meantime, if you want to provide the configuration via an environment variable then using `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` is the recommended approach.